# Which device nodes are managed by udev, and which by evdev?

Tags: linux, udev, evdev

From the wiki for evdev:

> evdev (short for 'event device') is a generic input event interface in
> the Linux kernel and FreeBSD.[1] It generalizes raw input events from
> device drivers and makes them available through character devices in
> the /dev/input/ directory.

And the wiki for udev:

> As the successor of devfsd and hotplug, udev primarily manages device
> nodes in the /dev directory. At the same time, udev also handles all
> user space events raised when hardware devices are added into the
> system or removed from it, including firmware loading as required by
> certain devices.

From what I understand udev will broadcast events and apply certain rules when a device is inserted/removed.  However, both appear to share the responsibility of creating device nodes under /dev/input (for evdev) and /dev (for udev).  Events can then be read from these device nodes.

What determines whether a device node is created by one vs. the other?